# Rails mailer for commenting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have created the mailer below to email you when a user comments on a music review that you had previously commented on. I don't want the email to be sent to the person doing the commenting (the commenter), but it is sending the email to them. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's my create in the comment controller:
    def create
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
    @comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user

```
if @comment.user != @pin.user
  MyMailer.comment_email(@pin.user).deliver
end  

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }

    @commenter = @pin.comments.collect(&:user)
    @commenter = @commenter.uniq

    @commenter.each do |commenter| 
      if commenter != @pin.user || commenter != @comment.user
        MyMailer.commenter_email(commenter).deliver
      end  
    end  

  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

The mailer:

```
def commenter_email(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: [user.email],               
  subject: 'Hi from theTens!')
end
```

I had thought that this (in the code above) would take care of not sending to the commenter:

```
commenter != @comment.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this block is sending email to unwanted person:

```
if commenter != @pin.user || commenter != @comment.user
  MyMailer.commenter_email(commenter).deliver
end
```

Based on your data you might want to change `||` to `&&`, or rework your logic in the `if` statement completely.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should compare via the database id's rather than by the objects. For instance:

```
commenter.id != @comment.user_id
```

The reason is that ruby may instantiate two objects that represent the same database record but they will be different objects with different object id's, so they won't be considered equal.